# Type of different internfaces

Tags: javascript, typescript

i those interfaces:

```
export interface EventCollectorData {
  eventType: EventCollectorType;
}

export interface ClickEventCollectorData extends EventCollectorData {
  elementData: EventCollectorElementLocator;
  eventType: EventCollectorType.CLICK;
}

export interface NetworkEventCollectorData extends EventCollectorData {
  eventType: EventCollectorType.REQUEST;
  requestData: {
    method: NetworkMethod;
    url: string;
    headers: Object;
    body: {
      json: Object | null;
      text: string | null;
      formData: any;
    };
  };
}

export type EventCollectorDataType = ClickEventCollectorData | NetworkEventCollectorData;
```

When I want to use the EventCollectorDataType and check if `elementData` or `requestData` is exists I'm getting this error:

> Property 'elementData' does not exist on type
> 'EventCollectorDataType'.   Property 'elementData' does not exist on
> type 'NetworkEventCollectorData'.

Here is an example for the function I want to do this check:

```
const check = (eventCollector: EventCollectorDataType) {
  if (eventCollector.elementData) {
    
  } else if (eventCollector.requestData) {
    
  }
}
```

How can I implement something like that?

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions or make a type guard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to narrow down what type you're dealing with before you access properties that only exist on one part of the union. The way you've set things up, the `eventType` property is perfect for this (it forms a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions)), so I recommend the following:

```
const check = (eventCollector: EventCollectorDataType) {
  if (eventCollector.eventType === EventCollectorType.CLICK) {
    // do stuff with eventCollector.elementData
  } else if (eventCollector.eventType === EventCollectorType.REQUEST) {
    // do stuff with eventCollector.requestData 
  }
}
```

An alternative way to narrow it down would be like this:

```
if ('elementData' in eventCollector) {
   
} else if ('requestData' in eventCollector) {
    
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i didn't notice that i could do that!